# XCode static library project share scheme?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, static-libraries

I have an `XCode` iPhone app project that includes a secondary project that builds a static library.

On the main project I have multiple schemes for building:

```
Debug, Release, AdHoc, AppStore
```

I duplicated these schemes in the imported library project.

My question is:

If I set the scheme to build for AppStore on the main project, will the static library be built with the AppStore scheme too?

Or do I need to set the scheme on both projects to make it work?

Comment: Did you use an Xcode Workspace to "encapsulate" (for want of a better word) both projects?

Comment: No, I just dragged the library project into the main project. Actually I created it directly inside the main project. So I still open the project with the main project file. No workspace.

Comment: If you use a Workspace then it works as you expect.  However I would have thought it work as you expect the way you have done it.  Funny thing is you can see, by looking at the log view, what it's doing, so why ask the question here?

Comment: How do you understand from the log if the application has been built with the optimization flag on (as per the Release build)?

Comment: Because you can see the command line (you have to expand the lines using the icon thing on the right, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Well done. I found it. As you suggested, the build configuration is shown in the build log. From what I see, the answer to my question is YES. Setting the scheme on the main project, will affect the static library too. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as suggested by trojanfoe, checking the build log in XCode clearly shows that the scheme I choose for the main project is therefore used to build the static library project too.